# Cannot find component with identifier JSF

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces

When I would like to run jsf page, I got this erreur

javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":form1:display" referenced from "form1:formateur".

This is JSF PAGE(index.xhtml) JSF + primefaces netbeans

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Gestion de réservation pour une formation</title>
    </h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    function handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, dialogName, formName) {  
            dialog = jQuery('#'+dialogName);
        if(args.validationFailed) {  
            dialog.effect("shake", { times:3 }, 100);  
        } else {
            clearForm(formName);
            ; 
            formateurDialog.hide(); 
        }  
    }
    function clearForm(formName){
        jQuery('#'+formName).each(function(){
            this.reset();
    });
    }
</script>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="150">
                <center>  <h1>Gestion de réservation pour une formation</h1></center>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200"  rendered="true" collapsible="true" resizable="true" closable="true" header="menu">
                <h:form>
                    <p:commandLink value="Nouveau formateur" actionListener="#{formateurController.preparerajouterFormateur(actionEvent)}" onclick="dlgFormateur.show();" />
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">

                    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlgFormateur" resizable="false"  height="400" width="450" header="Ajout formateur" position="center">
                <h:form id="newFormateurForm">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="nom"/>
                        <p:inputText id="adresse2" value="#{formateurController.formateurs.adresse}"/>

                        <h:outputText value="cin"/>
                        <p:inputText id="cin2" value="#{formateurController.formateurs.cin}"/>

                        <h:outputText value="email"/>
                        <p:inputText id="email2" value="#{formateurController.formateurs.email}"/>

                        <h:outputText value="nom"/>
                        <p:inputText id="nom2" value="#{formateurController.formateurs.nom}"/>

                        <h:outputText value="prenom"/>
                        <p:inputText id="prenom2" value="#{formateurController.formateurs.prenom}"/>

                        <h:outputText value="pseudo"/>
                        <p:inputText id="pseudo2" value="#{formateurController.formateurs.pseudo}"/>

                        <h:outputText value="sexe"/>
                        <p:inputText id="sexe2" value="#{formateurController.formateurs.sexe}"/>

                        <h:outputText value="telephone"/>
                        <p:inputText id="telephone2" value="#{formateurController.formateurs.telephone}"/>

                        <p:commandButton value="enregistrer" id="eng" actionListener="#{formateurController.ajouter(actionEvent)}" update=":form1:formateur" oncomplete="dlgFormateur.hide()"/>

                    </p:panelGrid> 
                </h:form>
                </p:dialog>

                <h:form id="form1">    
                    <p:dataTable id="formateur" value="#{formateurController.listFormateurs}" var="formateur" rowKey="#{formateur.formateurId}" paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur}" selectionMode="single" filteredValue="#{formateurController.filteredFormateurs}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20,30">
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form1:display" oncomplete="formateurDialog.show()" />  
                        <f:facet name="header">  
                            List of Formateurs  
                        </f:facet> 

                        <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{formateur.formateurId}" filterBy="#{formateur.formateurId}" id="id_formateur">  
                            #{formateur.formateurId}  

                            <p:commandLink value="#{formateur.formateurId}" update=":formateurDetailForm:display1" oncomplete="formateurDialog.show()"  title="View">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{formateur}" target="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur}" />    
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column headerText="Adresse" sortBy="#{formateur.adresse}" filterBy="#{formateur.adresse}" id="adresse">  
                            #{formateur.adresse}  
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column headerText="CIN" sortBy="#{formateur.cin}" filterBy="#{formateur.cin}" id="cin">  
                            #{formateur.cin}  
                        </p:column>  

                        <p:column headerText="Email" sortBy="#{formateur.email}" filterBy="#{formateur.email}" id="email">  
                            #{formateur.email}  
                        </p:column> 
                        <p:column headerText="Nom" sortBy="#{formateur.nom}" filterBy="#{formateur.nom}" id="nom">  
                            #{formateur.nom}  
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Prenom" sortBy="#{formateur.prenom}" filterBy="#{formateur.prenom}" id="prenom">  
                            #{formateur.prenom}  
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Pseudo" sortBy="#{formateur.pseudo}" filterBy="#{formateur.pseudo}" id="pseudo">  
                            #{formateur.pseudo}  
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Sexe" sortBy="#{formateur.sexe}" filterBy="#{formateur.sexe}" id="sexe">  
                            #{formateur.sexe}  
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Telephone" sortBy="#{formateur.telephone}" filterBy="#{formateur.telephone}" id="telephone">  
                            #{formateur.telephone}  
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Excluir" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:commandLink value="Excluir" action="#{formateurController.exclure()}" onclick="if(!confirm('Existe déjà #{formateur.nom}?'))return false;" update =":form1:formateur"/>
                        </p:column>



                    </p:dataTable>
                    </h:form>




                     <p:dialog header="Formateur Detail" widgetVar="formateurDialog" resizable="false" id="formateurDlg" > 
               <h:form id="formateurDetailForm">
                <p:panelGrid id="display1" columns="2"  style="margin:0 auto;">   
            <h:outputText value="Adresse :"></h:outputText>
                        <h:outputText value="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur.adresse}" />

            <h:outputText value="cin :"></h:outputText>
                        <h:inputText value="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur.cin}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Name!"/>

            <h:outputText value="email :"></h:outputText>
                        <h:inputText value="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please Enter Lastname!"/>

            <h:outputText value="nom :"></h:outputText>
                        <h:inputText value="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur.nom}"/>



            <h:outputText value="prenom :"></h:outputText>
                        <h:inputText value="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur.prenom}"/>

            <h:outputText value="pseudo :"></h:outputText>
                        <h:inputText value="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur.pseudo}"/>

            <h:outputText value="sexe :"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur.sexe}"/>

            <h:outputText value="telephone :"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{formateurController.selectedFormateur.telephone}" />
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton value="Update" update=":form1:dataTable, :growl"  oncomplete="handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, 'formateurDlg','newUserForm'); " actionListener="#{formateurController.modifier(actionEvent)}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid> 
             </h:form>
          </p:dialog> 

<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="5000" />



            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference components in JSF ajax? Cannot find component with identifier "foo" in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't have a component with id `display`, but I see one with `display1`. Secondly, `display1` is inside the form with id `formateurDetailForm`. Therefore, I bet your offending update attribute should say `:formateurDetailForm:display1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use tool already have inside FIREFOX, CHROME or any explorer to identify component id for what you need to UPDATE. "Using right click on Button or any component on your form and chose inspect element(Q) (this is on FIREFOX) and then you can see id what you need to use (update or any)" i think it can help you identify exactly what id of component to use :). GL